# Can't mount /system as RW

Tags: adb, malware, system

I own an old Motorola XT910  that has several malwares, so I'm trying to delete them from the `/system/app` folder (since they're set as system apps), but when I try to mount the system as read-write, via *adb shell* I get *Invalid argument*. I've tried many commands but no success. Anyone knows how this can be done?
What I've tried:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount , rw /system
mount rw, remount rw /system
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

The phone runs Android 4.1.2, rooted, BusyBox installed

Comment: You may like to try [Root Essentials](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superthomaslab.rootessentials)  . It does it for me well ( I am not comfortable with adb , so prefer an app). It is by one of our site regulars

Comment: But I've also tried with Terminal Emulator, the system just refuses to mount!

Comment: You have root on the device?  So when you type in "su" in the Terminal Emulator, it asked to grant root permissions and changed the $ to a #?

Comment: Permissions granted, $ > #

Comment: @beeshyams Not exactly the same problem...

Comment: Just to mention: the first two `mount` commands *are* invalid (`,`, `rw` and `remount` are no valid options – note the spaces in between). However, the last one looks valid. Do you perhaps get a different error message on that, like "permission denied"? Please also let us know the Android version running on your device, as that might well be relevant here.

Comment: No, I only get Invalid argument. Or if the comments are incorrect: Usage [-r] [-w] [-o] [-t] . The phone runs Android 4.1.2

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery I.e. TWRP? It can both mount /system, and allow you to delete the files you want to remove via its own File manager.

Comment: No, just the stock recovery. I finally mounted the system as rw.